# What is the point of the TableHeaderRow class

Tags: asp.net, .net

I've just converted some code from using `HtmlTable` controls to the web based `Table` controls and I found that in additional to the `TableRow` class there is also `TableHeaderRow`. I foolishly made the assumption based on some half read comments on here that if a row was one of these that it would be put in a `thead` element in the outputted HTML. It wasn't.

When this didn't work I looked close and noticed that `TableHeaderRow` seems to have no actual code on it and that the `TableSection` property of `TableRow` doesn't care if its a `TableHeaderRow` or not.

So what is the point of this type? It seems that in practice it is exactly identical to the TableRow class and you still have to set the `TableSection` property on it to tell it that its a `thead` row.

Is there a good use case scenario for this? I certainly can't think of one...

**Edit for clatification**

In my investigations I have used Refactor to look at the code involved. This is how I determined that `TableHeaderRow` seems to derive from `TableRow` but not actually implement anythign new.

In the rendering for `Table` when determining whether to output a `thead` or not it seems to look purely at the `TableSection` property. It doesn't care what the actual type of the row is and I can't find a single line of code anywhere that I've looked that would behave differently purely from the type of the row being different.

I'm looking for an actual practical example of how it differs. While I appreciate doc references they don't actually seem to match with the code I'm looking at.

Answer (score 4):

I wondered the same thing. When I saw the page 
[Creating ASP.NET table header row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849583/creating-asp-net-table-header-row) I realized that I was not setting the TableSection property as I should:

```
hRow.TableSection = Web.UI.WebControls.TableRowSection.TableHeader
```

It made the `<thead>` element to apear in the output html.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tableheaderrow.aspx):

> This class supports displaying tables on devices with a limited screen
>   size. On these devices, a table with many columns and rows must be
>   rendered across multiple pages. Adding a TableHeaderRow to a Table
>   control allows you to specify a heading row that is rendered as the
>   first row on each page that displays a view of the table.

I would infer from this that `TableRow` doesn't expose this kind of support.

Comment: This is how the `thead` tags work in web browsers in theory but I can't see anything that will make a `TableHeaderRow` render in a `thead` without specifying the `TableSection` property. Certainly in my tests it just rendered them as normal rows though that was on a normal desktop browser. Essentially I can't see that the above is actually true in my tests. `Table.RenderContents` just cares about that property when outputting `thead`,`tbody` and `tfoot` tags... Maybe I should edit the question to include some of this...

Comment: Are you rendering your table across multiple views?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by multiple views? I'm not sure how ASP.NET deals with different target devices and stuff. I didn't realise they even did different outputs to different targets (if that is what you are talking about). They are just being rendered via the normal method for a normal desktop web browser (IE/Firefox).

Comment: As per the quote above, a device where the table is split accross multiple pages.

Comment: My point is that I have no idea how .NET renders stuff out to different devices or indeed what devices would page an HTML table. The Table class looks like it only has one option for rendering and none of its derived classes seem to have anything more that I can see. So this question might be best answered by telling me other ways that the framework will render this as opposed to just calling its RenderContents method.