# Creating ASP.NET table header row

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I don't know why this isn't working. I'm trying to create a table header section from the back end code, but everything is going into tbody.

```
        Dim output As New Web.UI.WebControls.Table

        'Create the header row
        Dim hRow As New Web.UI.WebControls.TableHeaderRow
        hRow.TableSection = Web.UI.WebControls.TableRowSection.TableHeader
        hRow.Controls.Add(New Web.UI.WebControls.TableHeaderCell)

        For Each d As GridDate In Dates
            Dim hCell As New Web.UI.WebControls.TableHeaderCell
            hCell.Text = d.Value
            hRow.Controls.Add(hCell)
        Next
        output.Controls.Add(hRow)
```

The result is everything under tbody despite creating a header row and setting the section property to header. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Does your code also add rows with section of `TableRowSection.TableBody`?  If so, are you adding them **after** the headers?

Comment: I am. After that last line there is code to add additional rows. But as you can see this section is the first time any rows are added to the table.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the code I posted. In the last line of my code I was appending the new row to the controls collection:

```
output.Controls.Add(hRow)
```

Don't do this. It seems to bypass some of the properties unique to ASP.NET TableRows in final rending. In this case, it was ignoring the TableSection property despite being set correctly. You should append rows to the Rows collection instead:

```
output.Rows.Add(hRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim output As New Table
Dim hRow As New TableHeaderRow
For Each d As GridDate In Dates
    Dim hCell As New TableHeaderCell
    hCell.Text = d.Value
    hCell.Scope = TableHeaderScope.Column
    hRow.Cells.Add(hCell)
Next
output.Rows.Add(hRow)
```

This worked for me